# How to find a specific element and get a field value from a list of objects in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this block in thymeleaf where I'm trying to show the name of a protocolVersion isntead of the id. I only have the Id so I pass the list of protocolVersion (protocolVersions) and I'm iterating over it to show the one that matches the id (1007 is just a test).

```
<th:block th:each="item: ${protocolVersions}">
  <tr th:if="${item.id == 1007}">
    <td th:text="${item.name}"></td>
  </tr>
</th:block>
```

I'm getting the error message:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "item.id == 1007"

I've also tried something like this, as I've found it in one of the questions here:

```
<td th:if="${protocolVersions.?[id == '${excelMongoDoc.protocolVersionId}']}"
  th:text="${protocolVersions[id == '${excelMongoDoc.protocolVersionId}'].name}">
</td>
```

But this is not working either. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is simply: `${protocolVersions.^[id==1007].name}`.  So you could do this in your table:

```
<tr>
  <td th:text="${protocolVersions.^[id==1007].name}"></td>
</tr>
```

If you want to check against a variable, rather than hardcoding 1007 something like this:

```
<th:block th:with="check=1007">
  <td th:text="${protocolVersions.^[id==#root.check].name}"></td>
</th:block>
```

Comment: Also,  this is inside a <tr th:each="doc : ${documents}> and the value to compare is in doc.number. I've try to replace 1007 with ${doc.number} but no luck. Can you help with this please? is there any document explaining how to manipulate list? I can't find anything online. Thanks again

Comment: I've found out! I was missing brackets `th:with=(${doc.number})`